# ActionView DateHelper won't format certain numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, actionview

I'm moving a system to a new server. The code is the same on both servers. What *is* different (and wrong) is the output from methods within [DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html).

Both fine:

```
?> time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
=> "less than a minute"

?> time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 1.month)
=> "about 1 month"
```

Broken:

```
?> time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.days)
=> "¨¨count¼¼ days"
```

In the HTML this comes out as:

```
{{count}} days
```

What's up? There's no error messages and nothing in the log. Presumably I'm missing a gem, since it works on one server but not the other. But (if so) which gem?

Comment: Which rails version are you running?

Comment: 2.3.5 for the application, with 3.0.3 installed but not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your gem versions same on both systems? Interpolation variable format has changed from "{{count}}" to "%{count}" at some point. Especially check the [i18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n) version.

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation

Comment: I have i18b 0.5.0 on the faulty machine; the gem isn't installed at all on the working machine. I can't uninstall i18n though, since it has dependencies. There's plenty of differences in the installed gems, which is why I was hoping to narrow it down.

Comment: Perhaps you should unpack your gems on the old server and deploy your app with vendored gems to the new server. Check `rails:freeze:gems` and `gems:unpack` rake tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to avoid that, since it was partly down to gem issues that I switched servers.

Comment: Aha! Looking at i18n sent me down the right path - thanks. Paolo's answer here fixed my particular issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975532/have-rails-2-3-x-ignore-the-i18n-gem/3845215#3845215